# How Does Round Robin BP Selection Work In EOSIO?

Tags: dpos, bp

Is this a deterministic selection or is randomness introduced into BP selection?

What about state transition verification?

Are there any plans to improve BP selection?

Answer (score 4):

Every chain can choose to implement this however they like.

## On the EOS Mainnet

The round robin is deterministic, and cycles alphabetically through each of the block producers.

This actually causes occasional blocks to be missed due to latency, so there is a plan to introduce a latency-based cycle, where the BPs are placed next to their nearest geographical neighbours in order to reduce the number of missed blocks